# how to run asynchronously pil from pytnon

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-imaging-library, python-asyncio

i want to use pil Asynchronously, how can this be done?

```
from PIL import Image
import asyncio
async def test():
    image = Image.open("file.jpg")
    image = image.convert("L")
    image.save("file.jpg")
asyncio.run(test())
```

Comment: take a look at [`concurrent.futures` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) and [`asyncio.loop.run_in_executor` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor)

Comment: your code runs for me. What is your problem? PIL wasn't create to runs `asynchronously` so it may need to use `threading` or processing.